# Dataweave 2.0 Functions to transform a JSON to XML

Tags: dataweave

I am just learning DW2.0 and trying to transform the JSON to the XML below. I tried using Map but not able to get the desired o/p. Need suggestions on any functions that can be used to solve this.

JSON:

```
[{
        "id": "M-1",
        "type": "Product",
        "pricingDetails": [{
            "uLow": 2,
            "uHigh": 2,
            "unitPrice": 0
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "B-2",
        "pricingDetails": [{
                "uLow": 1000,
                "uHigh": 1000,
                "unitPrice": 0
            },
            {
                "uLow": 1000,
                "uHigh": null,
                "unitPrice": 0.56
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

o/p XML:

```
<ListOfPInfo>
<pInfo>
    <pId>M-1</pId>
    <uLow> 2</uLow
    <uHigh>2</uHigh>
    <unitPrice>0<unitPrice>
</pInfo>
<pInfo>
    <pId>B-2</pId>
    <uLow> 1000</uLow
    <uHigh>1000</uHigh>
    <unitPrice>0<unitPrice>
</pInfo>
<pInfo>
    <pId>B-2</pId>
    <uLow> 1000</uLow
    <uHigh></uHigh>
    <unitPrice>0.56<unitPrice>
</pInfo>
</ListOfPInfo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map over the pricing details after the main items, and convert the array into objects. It may be a bit non intuitive at first but I used reduce() to do the later.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    ListOfPInfo: (payload flatMap ((item, index) -> 
            item.pricingDetails 
                map {
                    pInfo: {
                        pId: item.id,
                        uLow: $.uLow,
                        uHigh: $.uHigh,
                        unitPrice: $.unitPrice
                    }
                } ) 
                reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ item)
    )
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ListOfPInfo>
  <pInfo>
    <pId>M-1</pId>
    <uLow>2</uLow>
    <uHigh>2</uHigh>
    <unitPrice>0</unitPrice>
  </pInfo>
  <pInfo>
    <pId>B-2</pId>
    <uLow>1000</uLow>
    <uHigh>1000</uHigh>
    <unitPrice>0</unitPrice>
  </pInfo>
  <pInfo>
    <pId>B-2</pId>
    <uLow>1000</uLow>
    <uHigh/>
    <unitPrice>0.56</unitPrice>
  </pInfo>
</ListOfPInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML outputs are one of the most complex ones. You need to consider that in XML you don't have arrays, but objects with repeated keys instead (something that JSON does not support). Pay attention to the `{(...)}` wrapping of the collection that basically merges all the objects created inside into a single one.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    ListOfPInfo: {(payload flatMap ((item, i1) -> 
        item.pricingDetails 
            map (pricingDetail, i2) -> {
                pInfo: {
                    pId: item.id,
                    uLow: pricingDetail.uLow,
                    uHigh: pricingDetail.uHigh,
                    unitPrice: pricingDetail.unitPrice
                }
            }
    ))}
}
```

You can check this blog entry too https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/how-to-tutorials/dataweave-generating-xml/

EDITED: Thanks @aled, I was missing that the price details can contain multiple entries so I need to do a double loop with map and flatMap.

Comment: it looks that there is a record missing.